# Removing dynamic tab pages from tab control

Tags: c#, dynamic, tabs, tabcontrol

I have a `TabControl` called `tc_Dashboard` what I want to do is add dynamic tabs to that `TabControl` and remove them dynamically as well.

This is what I use to make the first dynamic tab.

```
tabTitle = "+";
TabPage tab = new TabPage(tabTitle);
tc_Dashboard.Controls.Add(tab);
```

when I try to remove it using the following code its give me an `ArgumentNullException unhandled` error.

```
if(tc_Dashboard.SelectedTab.Text == "+")
{
    tc_Dashboard.TabPages.Remove(tc_Dashboard.TabPages["+"]);
}
```

I've tried searching online for a solution but without success
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: try `tc_Dashboard.TabPages.Remove(tc_Dashboard.SelectedTab)`

Comment: So it was this simple all along... Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simple solution is to remove `SelectedTab`

```
if(tc_Dashboard.SelectedTab.Text == "+")
     tc_Dashboard.TabPages.Remove(tc_Dashboard.SelectedTab)
```

> why original code doesn't work?

```
if(tc_Dashboard.SelectedTab.Text == "+")
{
    tc_Dashboard.TabPages.Remove(tc_Dashboard.TabPages["+"]);
}
```

`tc_Dashboard.TabPages["+"]` is null, because there is no page with `Name` equal to `+`. This code

```
tabTitle = "+";
TabPage tab = new TabPage(tabTitle);
tc_Dashboard.Controls.Add(tab);
```

creates new tab and set `Text` property, but `Name` is empty

if you set `Name` for created tab,

```
 TabPage tab = new TabPage(tabTitle) { Name = "+" };
```

`tc_Dashboard.TabPages["+"]` will return tabPage, not `null`